# WPF Binding pass through?

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls

I have a WPF UserControl that hosts another WPF UserControl, both of which I have made and expose various dependency properties. Now I have a DP called IsSelected in both and I need to bind the IsSelected from the internal UserControl to the IsSelected of the outer USerControl so that when the outer UserControl is used in a Window or Page I can be notified when a user selects the internal UserControl.

Does that make sense?

Update: I've tried with Xaml Relative Source binding but my internal control gets swapped by the user which means the Xaml binding is pointing to the wrong UserControl. Think of a Picture-in-Picture video control where the user can swap big picture with small picture, but it is always the big picture that drives the IsSelected property.

So my XAML looks like this

MainWindow.xaml...

```
<Grid>
    <MyControl1 />
</Grid>
```

MyControl1.xaml...

```
<Grid>
    <MyControl2 x:Name="myControl2" />
</Grid>
```

Both the DP properties on each control work great and bind correctly when I bind to them directly as seperate UserControls, I just can work out how to bind them together internally

In the code behind for MyControl1 I have tried variations on the following...

```
var bind = new Binding("IsSelected");
bind.Source = myControl2;
bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

this.SetBinding(MyControl1.IsSelectedProperty, bind);
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Cheers

Dave

Comment: Did you try something like `<MyControl2 x:Name="myControl2" IsSelected="{Binding Path=IsSelected, ElementName=myControl1}"/>`, where `myControl1` is set as `x:Name` on the containing UserControl?

Comment: Hey there is always a vital piece of info left out, sorry! The internal control get swapped with another by a mouse click on the control. It is a Picture-in-Picture control and the small video and the large video can be switched by the user. So the Xaml binding method only works until the user swaps the controls

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily using a [`RelativeSource Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the XAML alone. Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <ChildControl x:Name="myControl2" IsSelected="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={
         RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ParentControl}}}" />
</Grid>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

You have requested this `Binding` in code... unfortunately, I never do these `Binding`s in code, so I can't guarantee that this is correct, but it looks about right to me:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("IsSelected");
RelativeSource relativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor);
relativeSource.AncestorType = typeof(ParentControl);
binding.RelativeSource = relativeSource;
SetBinding(ChildControl.IsSelectedProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, however I missed some key info and have updated the question. Sorry to miss lead you.